# Im trying to get this sumif formula to check by whole column

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to get this formula and make it search the criteria by whole column.

I've tried switching the range to whole column but it doesn't work

This is the original code

```
=SUMIFS(T6,S6,">=0.5",S7,"E",U6,"Won")
```

I want to sum column T based by criteria 1 (same row),criteria 2 (the row below) and criteria 3 (same row)

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your worksheet?

Comment: share some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a column to the data?

If you can, you could enter something like this:

```
=IF(AND(S6>=0.5,S7="E",U6="Won"),T6,0)
```

somewhere on row 6, copy this down, then just sum the column you put the formula in.

Comment: Originally the formula is like this. but i would to add another checking which will find a certain value under the vallue ">=0.5" which was found.
=SUMIFS(T:T,S:S,">=0.5",U:U,"Won")